# if statement not working in python script

Tags: python, if-statement

In this script I am searching through a list of products that I pulled down from shopify. I am using a basic if statement to check if the variable named msrp is not = to the value 'None'. But for some reason this is not working.

```py
for item in data['products']:
    used = False
    name = item['title']
    url = 'https://' + brand[0] + brand[1] + '/products/' + str(item['handle'])
    handel = item['handle']
    for variant in item['variants']:
        msrp =  variant['compare_at_price']
        salePrice = variant['price']
        if msrp != 'None':
            print(msrp)
```

When I run this it prints out a lot of integers for msrp but it still dose print out 'None'. This is weird because I am checking to see if it is not 'None'.

Here is part of what it prints out

```
None
None
20.00
20.00
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Have you checked if this None is an Object None instead of 'None' string?

Comment: Also, including a sample of the data you are iterating on, would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
if msrp != 'None':
```

to

```
if msrp != None:
```

It's `None` as in `NoneType` not of `type(str)`

Comment: And then better to use `is not` with `None`, instead of `!=`. Also if you don't have other falsy values such as `0` to make it distinct from `None` you can just use `if not msrp:`

Comment: `!=` compares values whereas `is not` compares the reference, in case of checking `None`, either can work.

Comment: Made a typo: I meant `if msrp`. Yes I didn't say it doesn't work, it is *recommended* to use `is` for `None`, `True`, `False`. FYI `is` is faster than `==`.

Comment: @S.B, right, `is` is surely faster than arithmetic operators, because it compares the reference rather than the value which is the case of arithmetic operators.